# How to handle a late variable for a short moment before it is initialized?

Tags: flutter

In my app, I am using geolocator package to get the current location of the user. Everything works fine besides a second before the map UI loads. The problem is,

```
late Position currentLocation;
```

This variable is being set in a second. Before it sets the data, dart throws this error for a very short time:

> **LateInitializationError: Field 'currentLocation' has not been initialized.**

After that, everything goes back to normal. I tried not to use 'late' but then I got this error:

> **Non-nullable instance field 'currentLocation' must be initialized.  Try adding an initializer expression, or a generative constructor that initializes it, or mark it 'late'**

I tried using a CircularProgressIndicator in my map UI until it gets the value but it never becomes null anyway... What should I do in this kind of situation?
Here is my entire class if needed:

```
class ApplicationBloc with ChangeNotifier {
  final geoLocatorService = GeoLocatorService();
  final placesService = PlacesService();

  late Position currentLocation;
  List<PlaceSearch> searchResults = [];

  ApplicationBloc() {
    setCurrentLocation();
  }
  
  setCurrentLocation() async {
    currentLocation = await geoLocatorService.getCurrentLocation();
    notifyListeners();
  }

  searchPlaces(String searchTerm, double radius) async {
    searchResults = await placesService.getAutoComplete(searchTerm, radius);
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

Comment: Could you not make it `late` and assign some initial instance like `currentLocation = Position(0,0);` and replace it later with a real value?

Comment: When I did that, the map is started with that initial value. I also thought it will be replaced later but it is not replaced with the new value.

Comment: If it's not acceptable that the map loads with a default position, then we'll have to put the map in a `FutureBuilder` and rebuild when data is available and the map is acceptable to display.  Regarding the `currentLocation` not replacing with a new value, that's not related to `late` or not `late`.  Any variable that's not `final` can be updated.  So that's a coding error if it's not updating.

Comment: Okay, I will rebuild my code using a FutureBuilder then. Many thanks!

Comment: Welcome!  Good luck!